# Weird characters executing php from bash script

Tags: php, bash, permissions

I'm getting weird characters when I'm executing a bash script from a php page via shell_exec

Php script

```
shell_exec('bash /home/username/stage/getpicture.sh "url";
```

---

Here is the bash script

```
..some picture grab scripts..

title=$(php -r "echo urlencode(\"this is a test page\");")

echo "$title"
```

---

This is the result

```
+ÉÈ,Ö¢DíÔâíÄôTû/!
```

---

Permissions:

Php - when I run echo exec('whoami'); it gives "username"

Apache - running as "nobody"

Bash script - owner "username"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

at

```
php.ini
```